# Modifying button text and behaviour in GitHub issue template chooser

Tags: github

I'm working on adding custom templates for issues in a repository in GitHub. I've added the custom templates in the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE` folder, as well as a `config.yml` file to configure the template chooser. The config file looks like this:

```
blank_issues_enabled: true
contact_links:
  - name: Bug Report
    url: <URL_OF_TEMPLATE>
    about: Something isn't working as expected? Create a report to help us improve.
    context:
        button-text: Get Started
  - name: Feature Request 
    url: <URL_OF_TEMPLATE>
    about: Suggest a new idea or feature for <REPO>.
    context:
        button-text: Get Started
```

which gives me something that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to change the button text (and, if possible, open the template in the same tab on clicking the button), but I've not been able to find the right keyword(s) that will make the changes.

I've looked into GitHub's help pages for [setting up](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository) and [configuring the issue template chooser](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#configuring-the-template-chooser), but there's not much about configuring button text or on-click behaviour. I know it is possible to change it because it's done in [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Did you try *not* having the YML file? It looks on CRA like the name and description are just coming from the table at the top of each template. [This page](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository) suggests that's the "legacy" method, though.

Comment: Hmm, I tried not using the YML file but in that variant, I didn't use the table on top of the template. But nowhere in CRA's template file do they specify button text/behaviour, do they?

Comment: No, those are presumably the defaults for the legacy method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a custom text for a button.

The reason that the button of [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/new/choose) repository has a "custom text" is because it links to the security policy. That is not setup using the `config.yml`, but through an feature integrated into GitHub. In fact this repository does not even have a `config.yml`

You can read more about setting up a security policy [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/adding-a-security-policy-to-your-repository#adding-a-security-policy-to-your-repository).